# livekit cannot unmute track, remote unmute is disabled

Tags: go, livekit

I mute the participant track in the livekit room and this works fine, but when I want to unmute it through `MutePublishedTrack(Muted false)` I found an error `cannot unmute track, remote unmute is disabled` even though I have configured my server via `config.yaml` like this:

```
port: 7880
log_level: info
rtc:
  tcp_port: 7881
  port_range_start: 30000
  port_range_end: 40000
  use_external_ip: false
keys:
  devkey: secret
room:
  enabled_codecs:
    - mime: audio/opus
    - mime: audio/red
  enable_remote_unmute: true
turn:
  enabled: false
```

Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Comment: make sure that your config is actually loaded successfully. You could easily check for that by e.g. altering the log_level and see if the changes get applied as well.

Comment: I've fixed it, just by adding the `--config /pathto/config.yaml` in ExecStart on livekit-server.service so that the livekit server runs with the configuration that I have created